# how to identify code that triggers external javascript load?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-injection

I have a prestashop installation live which has been somehow injected with malitious code, here is my prestashop: https://debou.it

in chrome console I see this external javascript is loaded many times on every page load: https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js but I cannot locate the code that triggers it.

I went through all SO questions ad tried locating the code with Chrome DevTools without success, eg:
[Is possible to debug dynamic loading JavaScript by some debugger like WebKit, FireBug or IE8 Developer Tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705952/is-possible-to-debug-dynamic-loading-javascript-by-some-debugger-like-webkit-fi)
[How to find out which Javascript causes a jQuery Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208268/how-to-find-out-which-javascript-causes-a-jquery-ajax-request)

I'm working with an installation by an other developer, anyone can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference to anyone: it was yandex added to google tag manager. It's scam code, used to send russian spam to new contacts.
Removed it from GTM and everything works fine